White Board Renewal - Chemistry in Action
This is a hack, not a question.
After trying more than 20 various cures from the web for removing ghosts from the white board that didn't work.... I used the molecular attack.
Household bleach.  Wipe on.  Leave for an hour and let the hypochlorite oxidize the organic pigments from the marker, and then rinse off with water.  It chews the dyes from the marker into tiny chemical bits and the board is bright white again.  Alpha Mike Foxtrot.

This is a Question and Answer site. You should post a Question and then have a separate Answer (this allows others to also answer your question).

Or post an answer on the previous question.
